# PHP - Identify first image in array of files input

Tags: php, arrays, upload

I have the following PHP code for uploading images and moving them to a specified directory:

```
<?php

$i = 0;
foreach($_FILES['images']['name'] as $file) {

    $tmpFilePath = $_FILES['images']['tmp_name'][$i];

    $is_main = (($_FILES['images']['name'][0] == $file)) ? 'main' : $i;

    //Make sure we have a filepath
    if ($tmpFilePath != ""){

        $newFilePath = "./files/" . $is_main."_".$_FILES['images']['name'][$i];

        //Upload the file into the temp dir
        if(move_uploaded_file($tmpFilePath, $newFilePath)) {

        //Handle other code here

        }
    }
    $i++;
}

?>
```

This is my HTML input:

```
<input type="file" name="images[]" accept="image/*" multiple />
```

I am using a plugin in wich you can reorder the elements, below you can see that I can successfully upload the images and when I do a print_r($_POST) the output I get is this one:

```
Array (
    [title] => 
    [images] => Array
        (
           [0] => 2.png <---- correct order (I switched file 1.png with file 2.png so it works)
           [1] => 1.png
           [2] => 3.png
           [3] => 4.png
        )

    [submit] => Submit
)
```

But when I upload the files and rename them (see PHP code in the first box code) I set a variable called $is_main if the file is [0] it should be called "main" and the others don't really matter. **How can I accomplish this?**

The current output is that the first image I select is the main one, but after reordering it keeps to be the main one.

Comment: Why not use your `$i` iterator? `$is_main = $i==0 ? 'main' : $i;`

Comment: @showdev Sounds logical but it doesn't work even like that, it's still disordered

Comment: Maybe the "reorder" plugin is renaming your files? I don't see any file named "main" in your output.

Answer (score 1):

using your `$i` 
**UPDATE**  using for loop.

```
$tmpFilePath = $_FILES['images']['tmp_name'];
$is_main = $_FILES['images']['name'];
for ($i=0; $i < count($is_main); $i++) { 
    $tmp_image = $is_main[$i];
    $tmp_file = $tmpFilePath[$i];

    if($tmp_image == $is_main[0]){
        $ext = explode('.', $tmp_image); //getting an  extension
       $tmp_image = 'main.'.$ext[1]; // renaming the file
     }

    //Make sure we have a filepath
   if ($tmpFilePath != ""){

         $newFilePath = "./files/" . $tmp_image;

       //Upload the file into the temp dir
        if(move_uploaded_file($tmp_file, $newFilePath)) {

       //Handle other code here

       }
     }

    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but I'm still getting the same result, the first image is not being called "main"

Comment: @Daniel i have changed that code and now it uses a `for loop`, it's working on my side.

Comment: thank you, but I solved it with a simple line **$is_main = ($_FILES['images']['name'][$i] == $_POST['images'][0]) ? 'main' : $i;** --but marked your answer as useful :) Thank you

Answer (score 0):

On the first time you have to grab the file checksum and store it on SESSION like :

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['main_file'] = md5_file($files['images'][0]);
```

And when you do a re-order, or re-name or anything else you have to loop through each image and see if it's **md5** matched with the one you stored on session, if it does than this is the main image.